# Pattern matching map with exact list of keys

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

In order to validate some JSON documents, I need to ensure that my JSON (represented has a map) has a specific set of fields not more, not less.

From the best of my knowledge pattern matching with something like `#{a := FieldA} = MyJSON` only ensures that the key `a` is present in `MyJSON`.
Unfortunately `maps:with/2` ignores missing keys and most other maps functions work on a single key at the time.

In this case, what is the recommended way to ensure that a map contains a specific field or list of fields and not any other?

My current, ugly, solution is to pattern match all the keys I need and rebuild a new map like in:

```
validate(#{a := A, b := B, c := C}) ->
#{a => A, b => B, c => C}.
```

But it becomes very hard to maintain, very quickly.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use a `record` in those cases? Or at least a record/tuple (or any other structure that you know how it looks like beforehand) you can check against it.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ I could potentially use a proplist or tuple (that's output options from sile/jsone). But comparing two maps for the exact same keys is such a common use case and since not all the maps features have been implemented yet, I thought it would eventually be supported in either the matching syntax or the maps module.

Answer (score 3):

if i understand your problem well, this code should do what you want:

```
is_map_valid(Map,SortedKeyList) ->
    SortedKeyList == lists:sort(maps:keys(Map)).
```

tested in the shell:

```
1> Is_map_valid = fun(Map,SortedKeyList) -> SortedKeyList == lists:sort(maps:keys(Map)) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.99386804>
2> Map1 = #{a => 1, b => 2}.                                                                
#{a => 1,b => 2}
3> Map2 = #{a => 1, b => 2, c => 3}.
#{a => 1,b => 2,c => 3}
4> Map3 = #{a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4}.
#{a => 1,b => 2,c => 3,d => 4}
5> Keys = [a,b,c].
[a,b,c]
6> Is_map_valid(Map1,Keys).
false
7> Is_map_valid(Map2,Keys).
true
8> Is_map_valid(Map3,Keys).
false
9>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: use `maps:size` (or `erlang:map_size` if you need it in a guard condition) after `maps:with`, i.e. something like

```
validate(Keys, Map) -> 
    ExpectedSize = erlang:length(Keys),
    case maps:with(Keys, Map) of
        Map1 when erlang:map_size(Map1) == ExpectedSize -> {ok, Map1};
        _ -> invalid
    end.
```

You can also check `Map` size first to fail quickly.